# getResource() not locating the resource on classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath, classloader

I have set up basic maven project in java SE, with a resource:

```
main 
  -java
  -resources
    -config -> database.properties
```

now since I don't want this resource in the final jar, I define:

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>config/database.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-jar-ultimateParser</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                        <finalName>testApp</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <compress>false</compress>
                            <!-- Manifest - MainClass & ClassPath -->
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>aa.bb.Class</mainClass>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Class-Path>config/database.properties</Class-Path>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Copy configuration files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist/config</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So the resource is on classpath and the directory with the resource is copied to the final jar.

My manifest looks like this: "Class-Path: config/database.properties"

But I'm not able to read it:

```
String db = "/config/database.properties";
properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(db));
```

I tried absolute/relative paths, `getClass()/ClassLoader`. Nothing. It works flawlessly in NetBeans, but that's about it.

Comment: You're saying it works in NetBeans, but not in production? I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maven has it's own class loader which does interesting things. I suggest you print out `java.class.path` under maven, you might find it's shorter than you expect.

Comment: Can you print out the contents of the jar file maven packages?  Do you find a database.properties in it?

Comment: What is the intention of the exclude in the maven-jar-plugin configuration? Remote it. Remote the class-path from the manifest. Why are you configuring the maven-resources-plugin? Please show the full pom file. Furthermore you should change the code to **properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(db))**

Comment: This question makes no sense. You "don't want this resource in the final jar" but you're still trying to read it from the classpath?!? Where are you planning to put it? And why are you configuring the resources plugin, which exists to copy files into the output directory?

Comment: @ccleve I'm trying to remove database config from jar, so I don't have to recompile anytime I want change db settings.

Comment: @parsifal I'm planing to put the resource in config directory alongside to my jar

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan No my database.properties is not in the jar file. That is my goal I want the config file outside the jar so I could easily change it.

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok I added full pom, other questions I answered already..

Comment: @user987220 ok then how are you running the jar and what directory are you in when you try to run it?

Comment: I run: "java -jar testApp.jar" I'm in: "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetbeansProjects\TestProject\target\dist\"

Comment: And where is the database.properties file relative to that directory?

Comment: It's in relativly: ".\config", so "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetbeansProjects\TestProject\target\dist\config\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the Maven Resources plugin does. It simply copies resources (perhaps with transformation) into the build output directory. Where they're then included into the build artifact (JAR, WAR, whatever).

To make this work (referencing the JAR's directory using the `Class-Path` manifest entry), you need to distribute the config file separately. Or reference it using a `File`, and not bothering with the classpath.

A better approach is to distribute your application as an assembly, which contains the core app, any dependencies, and the configuration file. This would typically be packaged as a ZIPfile, and the user would unzip it to install.

Comment: Exactly I would have core.jar + ./libs + ./config But I can't read the resources from ./config in core.jar using getResource

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole point of /src/main/resources and should place these "configurable" files in /config and use File to read them

Comment: @user987220 - `src/main/resources` is a place to put non-compilable files that will end up in the final artifact. But you seem to be explicitly excluding them from that artifact, so there's no way for the application to find them.

Comment: well that pretty much explains it! Thanks a lot for clearing that up!

Comment: @user987220 - take a look at the Maven Assembly plugin; it really is the easiest way to package an application that might be modified after installation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are excluding it. Maven uses its own resources dir.
Project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src`
-- main
        `-- resources
wich it makes easier the life the programmer. Theres no need to get classpatch or other when you using this way.